# how to call a function contains kwargs with input function data?

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-input, keyword-argument

I have a function :

```
def myFunc(**kwargs):
    for username, password in kwargs.iteritems():
        print "%s = %s" % (username, password)
```

I want to receive username and password using input like this :

```
username = input("Enter username : ")
password = input("Enter password : ")
```

Then pass username and password to myFunc :

```
myFunc(username = password)
```

I know that it's not gonna working, but what is the solution to handle this job ?

*Note : both username and password may be different things in every iteration.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `**` syntax to expand a `dict` into its constituent key/value pairs. For example:

```
myFunc(**{username: password})
```

or

```
d = {}
d[username] = password
myFunc(**d)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just read them from `kwargs` if they exist:

```
def myFunc(**kwargs):
    print("username = " + kwargs["username"])
    print("password = " + kwargs["password"])

myFunc(username="jane", password="doe")
```